# Why is the $payload an empty variable?

Tags: shell, jenkins, github, webhooks, jenkins-github-plugin

**Software Versions:**
github-plugin version 1.29.3
Jenkins ver. 2.163
nginx reverse proxy

**Current State** No communication issues, and build triggers from the push event. However no values in $payload

**GitHub Configuration:**

**Github Webhook**: on repo
https://username:password@publicIP:port/github-webhook/

**Content type** (tested both application/x-www-form-url-urlencoded & application/json)

**Event type:** Just the push Event

..

**Jenkins Configuration:**

**GitHub Project:** Populated with the project URL

**This project is parameterized:** String parameter payload

**Source Code Management:** REPO URL & Creds Branch Master

**Build Triggers:** GitHub webhook trigger for GITScm polling

**Build Execute Shell:**

```
echo "the build worked! The payload is $payload"
```

**Output:** is blank for the $payload
`the build worked! The payload is`

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use the Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

Answer (score -1):

A simple quick and dirty way to parse "name" and "email" is the below, treating the JSON file as raw text (which has it's own caveats of course)

```
name=$(grep pusher -A5 <your_json_file> | grep  name | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d \" | tr -d ,)
email=$(grep pusher -A5 <your_json_file> | grep email | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d \" | tr -d ,)
```

Comment: So this implies that there is a <your_json_file> Which if there was this would work. However, i can't even get at the payload to write it to a file